# No instance of (Fractional Int) arising from use of '/'

Tags: haskell

I've run up against a wall.

This code

```
profileMatrix = map (map (\x -> (fst x, (snd x) / (length molseqs)))) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)
```

gives me this error

```
No instance of (Fractional Int) arising from a use of '/'
In the expression: (snd x) / (length molseqs)
In the expression: (fst x, (snd x) / (length molseqs))
In the first arguemnt of 'map' namely
  '(\x -> (fst x, (snd x) / (length molseqs)))'
```

Using fromIntegral also gives me an error:

```
profileMatrix = map (map (\x -> (fst x, (fromIntegral (snd x)) / (fromIntegral (length molseqs))))) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)
```

Even different combinations of fromIntegral gives the error:

```
profileMatrix = map (map (\x -> (fst x, (snd x) / (fromIntegral (length molseqs))))) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)

profileMatrix = map (map (\x -> (fst x, (fromIntegral (snd x)) / (length molseqs)))) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)
```

Some clarifications:

- `makeProfileMatrix molseqs` returns a `[[(Char, Int)]]` (a list of lists of touples, pairing Chars to Ints).
- This means that 'x' in the code will be a touple i.e `('A', 3)`, and this is confirmed to be working properly.

How do I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may use `quot` or `div` depending which way you want the rounding to go.

Comment: Problem is I need the answers to be fractional (they will all be between 0 and 1)

Comment: @Mossmyr Then you'll have to cast it from `Int` to `Float` or `Double`.  You can use the `fromIntegral` function for this.

Comment: @bheklilr I've done this in 3 different variations with the same result, see the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `makeProfileMatrix` does, or indeed what the type of `molseqs` is but here's something plausible that works -

```
> import Data.List (group)
> let molseqs = ["aaabb", "aabbcc", "aabccc"]
> let rle = map (\g -> (head g, length g)) . group
> let makeProfileMatrix = map rle
```

There's a slightly nicer way to define your original function

```
> let innerFunc xs = map $ \(a,b) -> (a, b / length xs)
> let pfm molseqs = map (innerFunc molseqs) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)
```

which results in the error "Could not deduce (Fractional Int) arising from..." error that you noticed. One way is to use `fromIntegral` to cast everything to a double first

```
> let innerFunc xs = map $ \(a,b) -> (a, fromIntegral b / fromIntegral (length xs))
> let pfm molseqs = map (innerFunc molseqs) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)
```

and now you should hopefully see something that you expect -

```
> makeProfileMatrix molseqs
[[('a',3),('b',2)],[('a',2),('b',2),('c',2)],[('a',2),('b',1),('c',3)]]

> pfm molseqs
[[('a',1.0),('b',0.6666666666666666)],[('a',0.6666666666666666),('b',0.6666666666666666),('c',0.6666666666666666)],[('a',0.6666666666666666),('b',0.3333333333333333),('c',1.0)]]
```

Comment: Definitely more readable and by breaking up the code into different functions, easier to test.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it. I get the results I want now, though I still don't know what was wrong with my previous code.

Answer (score 2):

**:t (/)** Takes to fractionals

**:t length** Returns an integer

You could use the `div` instruction instead. But I don't think you will get rounding.

Or you could wrap the return result of length into fromIntegral function.

Here's an example in my ghci.

(3) / (fromIntegral $ length [1,2,3])

I think fromIntegral will get you the rounding you want.

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me. Are you sure you are refreshing your scripts? If you are loading a script from the file into your ghci. You can use `:r` to reload the saved script.

Comment: In my ghci I posted the following.

let moseqs = [1,2,3]

let makeProfileMatrix a = [[('a',1)]]

profileMatrix = map (map (\x -> (fst x, (fromIntegral (snd x)) / (fromIntegral (length molseqs))))) (makeProfileMatrix molseqs)

and I got back [[('a', 0.33)]]

Comment: Yes, I've been saving the script between edits and reloading it with :r. Are you also using ghci?

Comment: This is really strange. When I enter the code into GHCI directly, it doesn't give me any errors (in fact it gives me exactly what I want), but when I try to compile my script with the code in it, I get the errors.

Comment: It sounds like a simple error. Maybe you aren't saving your script like you think you are. Maybe you are compiling an older script. Try commenting out everything in the file and save and see if you get a different error.